# start testng.xml from command prompt

Tags: command, testng, prompt

ok  i make some progress but still no luck :

my new command line is : java -cp C:\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20130607_0745/lib/testng.jar;C:\workspace\Worx_AutoTest\bin org.testng.TestNG C:\workspace\Worx_AutoTest\testng.xml

but the result is :

```
      ...
     ... TestNG 6.8.6beta_20130517_2142 by CÚdric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
     ...

    [TestRunner] Running the tests in 'Smoke Test in FF - FF REMOTE' with par
    ode:false
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/sel
    ebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector.checkMethod(XmlMethodSel
    ava:241)
    at org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector.setXmlClasses(XmlMethodS
    .java:259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initRunInfo(TestRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:230)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(
    nner.java:538)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDrive
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selnium/WebDriver
```

You should add selenium jar file to classpath. That's what the above message says.